# To remove related entities found next item get null in second step of foreach, EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Suppose we have snippet code like below to remove some navigate entities:

```
            User user = DBContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserID == userID); 
            foreach (string bookId in bookIds)
            {
                Book book2Remove = user.Books.SingleOrDefault(bk => bk.Id == bookId);  
                user.Books.Remove(book2Remove);
            } 
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

there is a relation many-to-many between `User` and `Book` but when I want to remove all the related `Books` that their `Id` are in `bookIds` array one by one it is remove just one of them (only first one) in the other words in next(second) `Foreach` step , the `book2Remove` will get null to end.

And the established relation in `onModelCreating()`:

```
 HasMany(t => t.Users)
            .WithMany(t => t.Books)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserBookMap");
                m.MapLeftKey("Id");
                m.MapRightKey("UserID");
            });
```

does anybody know why this is occurred?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an exception message? If so, then what is the message?

Comment: @CodeNotFound No, there is no any Exp.

Comment: why do you not include books on call? I'd think user.Books is null, not booktoremove. Unless there is no matching book in the loaded books list, then SingleOrDefault will return null.

Comment: can you show your models code also ?

Comment: @Sampath, Thank you for your reply, I did it by code-first approach, There are lot's of properties but `User` have a navigation prop as `ICollection` of `Book` and vice versa, a table `UserBookMap` in DB have `BookId` and `UserId` not more, everything work like a charm except mentioned prop...

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

```
User user = DBContext.Users
                     .Include(b => b.Books) 
                     .FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserID == userID); 

            foreach (string bookId in bookIds)
            {
                Book book2Remove = user.Books.FirstOrDefault(bk => bk.Id == bookId);  
                user.Books.Remove(book2Remove);
            } 

            DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use `Include` like yours, my Include parameter is `string` path, anyway I am looking for the reason...

Answer (score 0):

Oops my wrong, poor Code-First :), there is a prob, passed all IDs same 
but Ids are very large string (they are different in a small portion) so that is boring to check them :).

So what should I do, 
Remove the question or not ?